# .org or .com for a software product?

Tags: seo, domains

I like to setup a website for a software to share it or sell it, the domain with `.com` already has been registered but `.net` and `.org` are available,

I have seen some products in `.org`, should I use this affix for my website? 
Are there any advantage or disadvantage to use it over a `.com` website?

Comment: Sorry but this type of question has been asked in various forms across Pro Webmasters already. To avoid further disappointment please check through our help center.

Answer (score 0):

`.org` is for non commercial organization, not a product. For a product, you should choose another TLD like a `.com` for example.

For SEO, there is no advantage to use a `.org` instead of a `.com`.

However, to protect your product, you should buy the `.net` and the `.org` TLDs and 301 redirect them to the `.com`.

Comment: To protect you mean for abusing of the domain and confusion of customers?

Comment: By protecting, I mean to avoid that a competitor buy it to steal your business.